# On pavucontrol I can't change recording of Firefox

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

When I join a Google Meet meeting, my microphone is automatically chosen as *Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo* and there is no other choices in Google Meet settings.

[image: Google meet settings]

When Firefox asks for permission, it only asks for permission of *Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo* and there is no other choice on there, too.

[image: Screenshot of permissions dialog]

Lastly I tried changing from `pavucontrol`. I went to the *Recording* tab. This time there is a choice for selecting *Built-in Audio Analog Stereo* instead of *Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo*, but when I select it it doesn't change. It stays on *Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo*:

[image: Screenshot of Recording tab]

So I can't use my microphone in Google Meet. I have no problem on other applications, like Zoom or OBS studio. This problem is only on Google Meet.

Operating system: Xubuntu 20.04

Comment: I had the same issue, did what the answer to this question suggested: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452907/pavucontrol-wont-change-output-on-some-apps After reboot, it worked.

Comment: That didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Sounds ridiculous, but after change random configuration profile while something is playing sound, the recording setting is applied. I figured out after my remote nomachine changes playback device. Cost me 2 days.

[image]